# Long running time of sympy after opening a new console

Tags: python, runtime, sympy

I have a script with sympy that shows weird behaviour. If I open a new console (Ipython console in Anaconda, Spyder) and run the script it doesn't seem to terminate (takes longer than 1 minute).

However if I then abort the computation and run the script again it terminates within 2 seconds. Also if I run each line interactively it is fast. The difference is not the overhead in the importing libraries etc (timing is made without import).

Can somebody explain me this behaviour?
Can somebody please run the script so see whether it behaves similar on their computer?

Here's my script

```
import sympy as sy
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
a = sy.symbols("a")
A = sy.Matrix(3,3, a)

c0,c1,c2 = sy.symbols("c0 c1 c2", positive = True)

A = A*sy.diag(1,c1,c2)

equi12 = A[1:,1:].inv()*sy.Matrix([1,1])
equi01 = A[:2,:2].inv()*sy.Matrix([1,1])
equi02 = A[[0,2],[0,2]].inv()*sy.Matrix([1,1])

r_0 = 1 - sy.factor(A[0,1:]*equi12)[0]
r_1 = 1 - sy.factor(A[1,[0,2]]*equi02)[0]
r_2 = 1 - sy.factor(A[2,:2]*equi01)[0]

f_0 = 1
f_1 = 1
f_2 = 1
print("hi")
f_N0 = 1-A[0,0]*sy.factor(sy.Matrix([[1,1]])*equi12)[0]
f_N1 = 1-A[1,1]*sy.factor(sy.Matrix([[1,1]])*equi02)[0]
f_N2 = 1-A[2,2]*sy.factor(sy.Matrix([[1,1]])*equi01)[0]
print("ho")
ND_0 = sy.factor((r_0-f_N0)/(f_0-f_N0))
ND_1 = sy.factor((r_1-f_N1)/(f_0-f_N1))
ND_2 = sy.factor((r_2-f_N2)/(f_0-f_N2))
diff2 = sy.factor(ND_0- ND_1).args[-1]

print("checkpoint, so far so good")
start = timer()
# this is the step that causes difficulties
subs_c2 = sy.solveset(diff2,c2)
end = timer()
print(end-start)`
```

Answer (score 3):

SymPy has a cache, which caches the most expensive operations. In SymPy versions before 0.7.6, the cache is unbounded, which can lead to memory issues.

In 0.7.6 upward, the cache is an LRU cache, which uses less memory, but is a little slower. To get the speed back, you can install the package fastcache, which is an LRU cache written in C, which improves the performance by quite a bit.

You can dive deep into the sympy core caching logic to hit the bottom
[Source code for sympy.core.cache](http://docs.sympy.org/1.0/_modules/sympy/core/cache.html)